# Statically initialize field to point to another field

Tags: c, struct

I want to have a struct with an embedded array buffer and a pointer, which can either point to the embedded buffer or an external buffer:

```
struct s {
    char internal_buf[BUF_SIZE];
    char *active_buf;
};
```

I would like to **statically initialize** (as in a global variable) this structure such that the `active_buf` field points to the same struct's `internal_buf` field. In other words, something like:

```
struct s inst = {
    .internal_buf = {0},
    .active_buf = .internal_buf, // Doesn't compile unfortunately
};
```

Is this possible? I'm using GCC.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Huh? Of course it is possible! Just not with the syntax OP uses.

Comment: Why don't you try? Your syntax is wrong, but it is no problem.

Comment: @Olaf Really? Then I am going to learn something new, or I am missing the meaning of the question itself..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: As I understand, OP wants to set the address of the `internal_buf` field to `active_buf` in the initialiser. (OP: I intentionally don't show code. If you can't figure out yourself, you will not be able to use the `struct`). The definition is completed with the `=` (there is a sequence point).

Comment: @Olaf: Yep, I want the effect of `inst.active_buf = inst.internal_buf`, but done within the initializer itself rather than separately.

Comment: @Olaf Oh... I guess I've confused it with the struct type declaration itself. Just remembering not being able to set a size of one field base on the size of the others..

Comment: @AndrewSun: So, start thinking for yourself. You apparently have all parts  together. Just put them in place.

Comment: @Olaf: deleted my answer, I see your point, the OP is close. No need to spoil it for him :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre After some trial and error `.active_buf = inst.internal_buf` worked, silly me! I had no idea you could reference the variable before the initializer statement was complete. Mind un-deleting your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @AndrewSun Well, since you have figured it out, you can write the answer yourself :) And accept it..

Comment: An initialiser is not a statement, but part of the definition. But - as I wrote, there is a sequence point at the `=`, so the object is complete at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out the correct syntax for this is just:

```
struct s inst = {
    .internal_buf = {0},
    .active_buf = inst.internal_buf, // Works, address is known at compile-time
};
```